# Using Multiple Fonts

Tags: fonts

I am in the process of re-branding my company logo, webpage etc. I really like the "copperplate" font for the company name, however it is limited in that there is no bold option or lower-case option. I want to use another font and am curious if this is common practice? If it is, what should I be looking for to ensure the fonts don't clash?

Any help is appreciated!

/m

Answer (score 0):

Regarding lower-case, don't think you have any options when using "Copperplate". However regarding "bold", if using Illustrator you can add faux bold with a stroke. Then just increase weight as desired. However I suggest when your finalizing you duplicate (to keep live stroke version) then to Object > Expand [•]Object [•]Fill, then repeat that step, then Pathfinder > Unite.

I always work better with a visual, so included a snap where I'm highlighting the text so you can see the differences in the path.
[image]